# python def function and input

Tags: python, function, math, input

I am trying to set up a function using input , Is this possible ?

```
function = input('Please enter a function example')
def f(x): 
 return function 
print(f(2))
```

So if the function input is x**2 it should print the num 4 . I know this syntax is not right because functions is an alphanumeric object , but I need your help to understand how to make it right

Comment: Unless you abuse `eval` here, you're going to likely need to write an expression parser, which is no simple task. Is this just a toy project?

Comment: Take a look in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score -3):

**Disclaimer**: see comments, and no, you should not put this in a web page/service which people seem to assume you are writing. However for creating your toy calculator which you run locally at home, this built-in function is enough.
For safety, refer [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for really simple cases. [`simpleeval`](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/) has some nice wrapping for `ast`, which you may prefer to use as it is and/or learn from it (https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval/blob/master/simpleeval.py) **/disclaimer**

---

Assuming you mean the user can enter a function:

```
f = input("Function of x: ")
x = float(input("x: "))
print(eval(f))
```

Then enter `x+2` for the first input, `2` for the second, and see the result becoming `4`:

> ```
> Function of x: x+2
> x: 2
> 4
> ```

For making it more versatile, you may want to import everything from `math`:

```
from math import *
f = input("Function of x: ")
x = float(input("x: "))
print(eval(f))
```

then you can input `cos(x)` for example:

> ```
> Function of x: cos(x)
> x: 3.1415
> -0.9999999957076562
> ```

Comment: `eval` on untrusted user inputs is pure evil.

Comment: Which is nothing better.

Comment: The OP wants to evaluate certain mathematical expressions, not arbitrary Python expressions. `eval` should not be considered a suitable solution just because the former is a tiny subset of the latter.

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks, that is interesting, you may downvote now :-)

Answer (score -3):

I assume that you mean letting a user enter code (the function) as the input. If this is the case this might be a duplicate from:

[In Python: How do I convert a user input into a piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259975/in-python-how-do-i-convert-a-user-input-into-a-piece-of-code)